# How to find the fastest route in a maze (in C)

Tags: c, recursion, maze

The maze is defined as a square matrix.
For example:

```
int maze[N][N] =
  { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 } };
```

You can walk only where there's a 1.
You can take a step down, up, left, right.
You start at the top-left corner and finish at down-right corner.

The output should be the minimum steps to finish any maze.
We can assume there is at least one way to finish the maze.
i've edited the code and i thought i covered everything.. but obviously i'm missing something.
thanks for your help

```
int path_help(int maze[][N], int row, int col, int count)
{
    int copy1[N][N], copy2[N][N], copy3[N][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            copy1[i][j] = maze[i][j];
            copy2[i][j] = maze[i][j];
            copy3[i][j] = maze[i][j];
        }
    }
    int a, b, c, d;
    if (col == 0 || row == 0)
    {
        if (row == N - 1)
        {
            if (maze[row][col + 1] == 1)
            {
                maze[row][col] = 0;
                return path_help(maze, row, col + 1, count + 1);
            }
            else return N*N;
        }
        if (col == N - 1)
        {
            if (maze[row + 1][col] == 1)
            {
                maze[row][col] = 0;
                return path_help(maze, row + 1, col, count + 1);
            }
            else return N*N;
        }
        if (maze[row][col + 1] == 1 && maze[row + 1][col] == 1)
        {
            maze[row][col] = 0;
            copy1[row][col] = 0;
            return min(path_help(copy1, row, col + 1, count + 1),path_help(maze, row + 1, col, count + 1));
    }
    if (maze[row][col + 1] == 0 && maze[row + 1][col] == 1)
    {
        maze[row][col] = 0;
        return path_help(maze, row + 1, col, count + 1);
    }
    if (maze[row + 1][col] == 0 && maze[row][col + 1] == 1)
    {
        maze[row][col] = 0;
        return path_help(maze, row, col + 1, count + 1);
    }
    else return N*N;
}
if (col == N - 1 || row == N - 1)
{
    if (col == N - 1 && row == N - 1) return count;
    if (row == N - 1)
    {
        if (maze[row - 1][col] == 1 && maze[row][col + 1] == 1)
        {
            maze[row][col] = 0;
            copy1[row][col] = 0;
            return min(path_help(copy1, row, col + 1, count + 1), path_help(maze, row - 1, col, count + 1));
        }

        if (maze[row - 1][col] == 0 && maze[row][col + 1] == 1)
        {
            maze[row][col] = 0;
            return path_help(maze, row, col + 1, count + 1);
        }
        if (maze[row][col + 1] == 0 && maze[row - 1][col] == 1)
        {
            maze[row][col] = 0;
            return path_help(maze, row - 1, col, count + 1);
        }
        else return N*N;
    }
    if (col == N - 1)
    {
        if (maze[row + 1][col] == 1 && maze[row][col - 1] == 1)
        {
            maze[row][col] = 0;
            copy1[row][col] = 0;
            return min(path_help(copy1, row, col - 1, count + 1), path_help(maze, row + 1, col, count + 1));
        }

        if (maze[row + 1][col] == 0 && maze[row][col - 1] == 1)
        {
            maze[row][col] = 0;
            return path_help(maze, row, col - 1, count + 1);
        }
        if (maze[row][col - 1] == 0 && maze[row + 1][col] == 1)
        {
            maze[row][col] = 0;
            return path_help(maze, row + 1, col, count + 1);
        }
        else return N*N;
    }
}
if (maze[row + 1][col] == 1)
{
    maze[row][col] = 0;
    a = path_help(maze, row + 1, col, count + 1);
}
else a = N*N;
if (maze[row - 1][col] == 1)
{
    copy1[row][col] = 0;
    b = path_help(copy1, row - 1, col, count + 1);
}
else b = N*N;
if (maze[row][col + 1] == 1)
{
    copy2[row][col] = 0;
    c = path_help(copy2, row, col + 1, count + 1);
}
else c = N*N;
if (maze[row][col - 1] == 1)
{
    copy3[row][col] = 0;
    d = path_help(copy3, row, col - 1, count + 1);
}
else d = N*N;
return min(min(a, b),min( c, d));
```

}

Comment: What does not work. What is the output of your program and what output do you expect? Have you any ideas what could go wrong?

Comment: That's evil: a nested `switch` within a `switch` without proper indentation!  I'm not surprised it doesn't work.  I'm mildly surprised it compiles, but then there is [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) so I'm not wholly surprised.

Comment: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)

Comment: How does your code know where it has been?  How does it know when it has reached an edge?  How does it know when it has got the entire path?

Comment: ... and where are the start and end points?

Comment: Jonathan Leffler i dont understand where there is a wrong indentation.

Comment: Surely, as others have suggested, it's missing an 'I'm off the grid' failure return?

Comment: but theres no option for that to happend will . im pretty sure i made sure of that.

Comment: suggest implementing a version of Dijkstra's algorithm with a directed goal rather than getting the shortest path to every node.

Comment: Is the minimum possible answer for any maze `width + height - 2`?

Comment: Also, if the maze is always square, there is no need for passing N twice.  In fact, in this case, it's one of those every few cases where I would use a static maze.

Comment: @ofersimchovitch: After I edited the code, there was no longer improper indentation.  Maybe the trouble was that you were using tabs; it is best not to use tabs on Stack Overflow (or the other Stack Exchange sites).  I'm not convinced that the choice of nested `switch` statements is the best way to write the code; I think an `if` would be appropriate for the outer `switch` (and I reserve judgement on the inner `switch`).

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no solution of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) in the question linked by @Jackson, here is a modified algorithm adapted for this maze problem. I take the maze value `0` as no-go, and `1` as the distance for the algorithm.

It looks as though the `neigh()` function should be recursive, but it is not, it is only there so that 4 neighbours can be examined in the same way. Note that not every path is followed: for a large maze that could be O(no!). Also that the search is not *directed* to the end point: the end point is encountered, and these features of the algorithm give it its beauty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MSIZE  7                            // matrix/maze dims

enum ntype { virgin, listed, visited };     // for status field

typedef struct {
    int x;                                  // grid position of node
    int y;                                  // grid position of node
    int value;                              // 0 or 1 as defined in maze[][]
    int dist;                               // distance from start node
    int status;                             // enum as above
} node_t;

int maze[MSIZE][MSIZE] =                     // maze definition
  { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 } };

node_t node [MSIZE][MSIZE];                 // working array
node_t *list[MSIZE*MSIZE];                  // array of current node pointers
int listlen;                                // num elements in list[]

void neigh(node_t *cptr, int dx, int dy)
// examine one neighbour of node cptr, offset by dx,dy
{
    node_t *nptr;                           // pointer to neighbour
    int dist;                               // accumulated distance from start
    int x = cptr->x + dx;                   // work out neighbour coords
    int y = cptr->y + dy;                   // work out neighbour coords
    if (x < 0 || x >= MSIZE || y < 0 || y >= MSIZE)
        return;                             // failed edge test    
    nptr = &node[y][x];                     // point to neighbour
    if (nptr->value == 0)                   // no-go node
        return;
    if (nptr->status == visited)            // do no re-visit
        return;

    dist = cptr->dist + nptr->value;        // accumulate distance from start
    if (dist < nptr->dist)                  // if it's less than what was known...
        nptr->dist = dist;                  // ...update with the new distance
    if (nptr->status == virgin) {           // if it's never been seen...
        list[listlen++] = nptr;             // ... neighbour to list
        nptr->status = listed;              // and set its status
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, smallest, smallind;
    node_t *cptr, *eptr;

    // init the struct array
    for (j=0; j<MSIZE; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<MSIZE; i++) {
            cptr = &node[j][i];             // pointer to the array element
            cptr->value = maze[j][i];       // the maze definition
            cptr->x = i;                    // self's position
            cptr->y = j;                    // self's position
            cptr->dist = INT_MAX;           // distance from start (unknown)
            cptr->status = virgin;          // never examined
        }
    }

    eptr = &node[MSIZE-1][MSIZE-1];         // pointer to end node

    cptr = &node[0][0];                     // pointer to start node
    cptr->dist  = 0;                        // distance of start node from itself!

    // main loop
    while (cptr != eptr) {                  // until we reach the target node
        cptr->status = visited;             // we've been here now
        neigh(cptr,  0, -1);                // examine node above
        neigh(cptr, -1, 0);                 // examine node on left
        neigh(cptr,  1, 0);                 // examine node on right
        neigh(cptr,  0, 1);                 // examine node below

        // find smallest distance of nodes in list[] (won't include virgins)
        smallest = INT_MAX;
        smallind = -1;                      // set invalid marker index
        for (i=0; i<listlen; i++) {
            if (smallest > list[i]->dist) { // compare distance with smallest
                smallest = list[i]->dist;   // remembers the smallest
                smallind = i;               // remembers the list index of smallest
            }
        }
        // take smallest for next time and remove from list
        if(smallind < 0) {                  // -1 was the "marker"
            printf("No route found\n");
            return 1;
        }
        cptr = list[smallind];              // smallest becomes current node
        if (listlen)                        // replace in list with last element...
           list[smallind] = list[--listlen];// ... and reduce list length
    }                                       // now examine this node

    printf("Distance = %d\n", eptr->dist);  // show the distance of the end node
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Distance = 12
```

**EDIT** The algorithm itself is described in the link, if it breaks there are sure to be other explanations available. I have added more comments to the code.

I use 3 arrays, `maze[][]` is a simple maze definition like yours. Then `node[][]` is an array of `struct` which hold runtime data. I could have initiliased this with the maze definition directly, but because the program this came from had hard-coded test data of one matrix size, and a bigger matrix with data read from file, I left it as it was.

The third array `list[]` is an array of pointers to the `node[][]` elements. This is why `node[][]` elements contain the `x,y` coordinates within the struct itself: so that I can know the position from the pointer alone. I could have worked with a 1-D maze array, when I could have stored a single index in `list[]`, if so this complication would not have been necessary. But I used a 2-D array, just because it felt "nicer".

I am comfortable working with pointers. In the first nested loop pair in `main()` headed `// init the struct array` the first thing I do is to make a pointer, for use in setting the `struct` fields, because I find the repeated use of array indexing clumsy. So I write for example `cptr->x = i;` which has the same intent as `node[j][i].x = i;`.

Comment: Weather Vane since we havnt learned yet some of the sintax u've put here, can u describe in words what's happening here? thank u so much!

Comment: @ofersimchovitch I have edited my answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, this is a search problem. There are lots of well written posts on how to solve it, so I'll talk about a few of the finer points that your will need to consider.

Since you specify want the shortest path, and not just a "pretty good" path, you will need to check every possible route. Depth-first search would be my suggestion.

Most obviously, this is search without reuse. The shortest path will not contain any loops or any case where the cursor will return to a place where it has already been. This keeps the search area reasonable.

Comment: I would set the 1's to 0's as I went and, if the path failed, set them back again upon the returns.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm works *without* following every possible route: that's part of it's beauty - it is not directed at the endpoint, but encounters it.

Answer (score 0):

If runtime is not an issue, you can write a function to try every possible route, and returning the minimum.

```
int path_helper(int maze[][N],int height, int width, int row, int col){
  if(row==height-1 && col == width-1) return 0;
  if(maze[row][col]==0) return height*width;
  if(col<0 || row<0 || row>=height || col>=width) return height*width;
  maze[row][col]=0;
  int maze2[7][7]={{0}};
  for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      maze2[j][i]=maze[j][i];
  }
  return min(min(path_helper(maze2,height,width,row+1,col),
  path_helper(maze2,height,width,row-1,col)),      min(path_helper(maze2,height,width,row,col+1),path_helper(maze2,height,width,row,col-1)))+1;
}
```

it's ugly but it should do the trick

Comment: What about the edge conditions?

Comment: I did not consider that. I just fixed it. Thx

Comment: cemersoz i tried your code and it overflood the memory stack. is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The code did not check for loops so it could go between two points infinitely.  making the current point 0 should solve it. sorry foe the issue

Comment: i dont know why, for some reason it still returns 49

Comment: i think since we change maze[row][col] to be 0, the other calls for the function cant enter this index therefore the fastest way has been "ruined"

Comment: I am getting 16 using the same code. I don't think that is the issue since every point calls the function using its own value. I am working on it. :D

Comment: Solved it! Turns out I'm a moron. you have to make another array. since what you said is true even though it should not return 49. Editing it rn

Comment: as u can see in my edited code, i've tried to make 3 copies of the maze but still it didnt work