# How to print the BFS path from a source to a target in a maze (Or how to get the first move)?

Tags: c, graph, path-finding, maze

This is a question related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927485/how-to-print-the-bfs-path-from-a-source-to-a-target-in-a-maze) where you helped me a lot.

My new question is, is there a way to print the found path from the `source` cell to the `target` cell? Or, is there a way to get only the first move from `pred` without iterating all of it?

In the (Very helpful) answer I received in the other question I was suggested to get the path from `target` to `source`, that is very useful but in order to improve my code I'd the path from `source` to `target`.

My problem is that I'm trying to write a rogue-like game and I have to tell a monster which will be his next move and I think iterating all of the `pred` array in order to get a single move it's a waste of resources.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have a path mapped out, look for the next `*` beside the monster:

```
if (G->nodes[T.row + A][T.col + B] == '*') {
    //kept for my sanity: pred[G->T.row*G->col + G->T.col]

    doMove(); //don't forget to change the '*' into 'T', then the old spot to ' '
}
```

To do a move up, check `A = -1; B = 0`. To do a move down, check `offsetA = 1; offsetB = 0`. Right: `A = 0; B = -1`, Left: `A = 0; B = 1`.

Because your maps are very simple and don't branch very far, I recommend you choose a faster algorithm. BFS tends to search for the *nearest* paths and isn't very efficient for long paths. Djikstra's is a better implementation of BFS allowing a cost to be assigned to edges.  A* is the best search to use in games because it is Djikstra's algorithm that speeds up (converges faster) when it has no obstacles by exploiting knowledge of its goal.