# Finding the number of vertices within less or equal distance d of vertex x

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, graph-traversal

I have to use a graph traversal ( i was thinking of BST) to determine how many vertex in g are in a distance of v in less or equal to N , this is , a travel wich the distance is N ou less edges.

```
int succN (Grafo g, int v, int N)
```

I have this struct to work with :

```
#define MAX 100

typedef int WEIGHT;

struct edge {
   int dest;
   WEIGHT weight;
   struct edge *next;
};

typedef struct edge Edge;
typedef struct edge *GraphL[MAX];
```

I'm having a difficult time to make a efficient solution  in c. The only way i'm seeing right now its to make a recursive call in an aux function with the BST

Comment: You could explore Dijkstra's algorithm. Depending on the loop condition, you can either find a shortest route to a target node without necessarily visiting all nodes; or visit all nodes (once) and find the shortest distance to each from the start. Both uses make an efficient algorithm.

Comment: @WeatherVane In this particular case the weight is 1 , there for its not  a weighted graph . Can i still use Dijkstra's algorhim ?

Comment: Yes you can do.

Comment: Can you modify the structure? E.g., add fields for a stack.

Comment: Here is an example of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256346/how-to-find-the-fastest-route-in-a-maze-in-c/34257513#34257513) in another context but the ideas will be the same. I don't usually need a *call* to explore neighbours (Dijkstra is *not* recursive) but it was convenient here. How you explore linked nodes varies with their encoding method - perhaps a linked list of connected nodes. The example finds one shortest route, but if the main loop is changed to `while(1)` and you break when `listlen == 0` you will find the distance of all nodes from the start node.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat i can't modify the structure unfortunately .

Comment: @WeatherVane i'm going to take a look at that solution

Answer (score 1):

If your weights are nonnegative, you can use Dijkstra algorithm
Here is a simple pseudo-code. It has a `O(n^2)` time complexity (`n` = number of nodes).

```
ans = 0
dist[0 .. n-1, None] = {INF, ..., INF}
dist[v] = 0
iterate n times
   best = None

   for each node u
      if not seen[u] and dist[u] < dist[best]
         best = u

   if dist[best] > N
      break

   seen[best] = true
   ans++
   for each edge from best (going to v, of weight w)
      if dist[best] + w < dist[v]
         dist[v] = dist[best] + w

return ans
```

If all your weights are equal to 1 (as you are pointing out in comments), then a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) will be enough.